# Hibernate ConstraintViolationException: ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA.

```
  +--------------+      +-----------------+    +-------------------+
  |   map_range  |      |  map_location   |    |   location_map    |
  +--------------+      +-----------------+    +-------------------+
  |     ID       |      |     MAP_ID      |    |      ID           |
  |     RANGE    |      |     LOC_ID      |    |     LATITUDE      |
  |     RADIUS   |      |                 |    |     LONGITUDE     |
  +--------------+      +-----------------+    +-------------------+
```

**MapRange.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "map_range")
@XmlRootElement(name = "map_range")
public class MapRange extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "RADIUS", nullable = false)
    private Integer radius;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "map_location", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "MAP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<LocationMap> locations;
```

**LocationMap.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location_map")
@XmlRootElement(name = "location_map")
public class LocationMap extends AbstractDomain<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal latitude;

    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal longitude;
```

When I call the following:

```
super.merge(mapRange);

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, attached);
    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    attached = entityManager.merge(attached);
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> 11:45:11,577 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-5)
> ```
>
> SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
>       11:45:11,578 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-5)
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ebdb`.`map_location`, CONSTRAINT `fk_map_loc_map` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`LOC_ID`) REFERENCES `map_range` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE
>   NO ACTION)
>       11:45:11,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default
>   task-5) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC
>   statements
>       11:45:11,579 ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] (default task-5)
>   HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement]

If anyone can give some advise on how I can fix this issue, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: How do you create the instances of the entities? You just show us you're calling the `merge` operation, but don't show us how they are created and mapped.

Comment: @Richard What `BeanUtils` do you use?